# How to interpret featureVector and score in IBM Retrieve&Rank results?

Tags: ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

There are follow fields in fcselect results, for each result, 'score, featureVector'. Score max value is 10, while featureVector can be "1.8894386 0.94715786 0.39159727 0.96143353 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.13101925 0.01616435 0.0 0.01616435 1.5496718 0.7325779 0.27778885 0.7465826 0.75 0 0.6931471805599453 10.0"

What score=10 means? is 10 the maximum match? What featureVector means for my result?

Answer (score 0):

The `featureVector` field returned by the /fcselect endpoint is intended for generating input data for a "learning to rank algorithm". You may wish to take a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank) for an initial overview or the [training data reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/training_data.html#manual). The latter points out that /fcselect only returns these feature vectors if the parameter `&returnRSInput=true` is set in the request.

The `score` is the actual value that can be used to order the results from most relevant to least on your search page (though the presentation is already pre-sorted in the response).  Refer to the [API reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/#rank) for additional detail.